# About the Fibonacci "continued fractions"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Fibonacci used a different version of continued fraction which I'm curious about. It seems the notation is equivalent to
$$[a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots]=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3}+\cdots,$$
where $a_k$ are positive integers and (I *believe*) it is required that $1 \le a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le \cdots .$
The reason for my belief is that if we drop the nondecreasing assumption uniqueness is lost.

What I'd like to see is a proof (or reference to one) that each positive real has a unique such expression. Or just a reference to this type of "continued fraction" which I could follow up on.

Comment: What you refer to is an [Engel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion) and the attribution to Fibonacci is unsupported.

Comment: @Somos -- the link you give refers to Fibonacci's fractions, which I also saw in Burton's "Intro to Number Theory" book.

Comment: @Somos The exact title is "Elementary Number Theory" for the Burton book. He only mentions it briefly as an introduction to the modern version, see chapter 15 (section 15.2] I hadn't heard of Engel expansions (or maybe that would have stopped my even asking the question). But thanks much for that reference, which I can now follow up on.

Comment: The Engel expansion article does mention a connection to Fibonacci and continued fractions so the attribution to Fibonacci is partly correct after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be a positive real number. Take $a_1>0$ minimal such that $\frac{1}{a_1} < x_1$ and set $x_2 = a_1x_1 - 1$. Note that $x_2$ is positive and by the minimality of $a_1$ we have
$$
x_1 \le \frac{1}{a_1-1}
$$
which is equivalent to $x_2\le x_1$. Now letting $a_2>0$ be minimal such that $\frac{1}{a_2} < x_2$ we must have $a_2\ge a_1$ and obtained 
$$
x_1 = \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{x_2}{a_1} = \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_1a_2} + \frac{x_2a_2-1}{a_1a_2}.
$$
Repeating this, setting $x_{i+1} = x_i a_i-1$ in each step, should yield the desired unique expansion.